# Question about questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am not sure that I am going to express myself correctly here or even if this subject will be seen with favor, so I beg for your understanding if I go amiss.

Would it be possible to make questions on the main site that are done by the community and not from a individual that would normally too broad for this site, in order to both make it more appealing to newcomers as well as having a type of general list questions? This way people could continuously add their answers to the question.

For example:

What drinks could be paired with the celebration of Catholic saints feast days? (Please explain the reasons for your Choice).  I am sure some of you out there could come up with some type of list question also.

If this question is looked on in a negative light, I am good with that for at lest I can see how the site would like to progress!

Answer (score 4):

I share your desire to increase participation.  The SE platform doesn't work well for "list" questions like that, in general.  You end up with partial information scattered among 35 different answers, none complete, and it's hard to manage.

An approach that *can* work is to have a single community-wiki answer that compiles all the information.  [Local beers to try at airports (major airports only)](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/580/local-beers-to-try-at-airports-major-airports-only) was an early question that did that, but was ultimately closed as too broad.  It seems like this approach could work well for some questions, though -- to use your example, a community-wiki answer that lists the saints' days and compiles thematic drinks for each.  (I don't know anything about the culinary aspect of saints' days, so I don't know if that's feasible.)  On the other hand, if your question is about what to serve for St. Crispin's Day, ask that!  It's focused, searchable, and (I presume) answerable, without having the "big pile of fragmented answers" effect.  We've had some individual questions for specific days and I think those have worked well.

I don't have a good answer here, but I thank you for asking the question and I hope others will weigh in.

Comment: i would agree that the main issue with things like this is that the answers are hard to keep track of there is no way to say that a answer is right or wrong and how many answers will be enough for the asker, i agree the best thing to do would be a community wiki answer but once again this would still take time to compile its a hard area to look on as some list questions can be really good and some can just end up a mess of two or three item answers

Comment: The partial information scattered over a lot of answers is a problem - I don't know how this works but can't they be edited - sorry mods sounds like a job for you lot!  Oh well, that's my 2 cents worth!

Comment: @JamieEltringham Would it be possible to do a similar question of sorts, but the responses form one  large **Wiki Post** as I did with this question: [How do Catholics observe Lent through a dignified and appropriate use of food?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/68138/25495)

Comment: @KenGraham I think that in cases like that i would say it would be fine as the answer although it is long has all the details and can clear up any misconceptions so i would say that that would be fine

Answer (score 2):

If the question involved would make reference to the fact that the response (answer) would be a community wiki post answer only be acceptable. This way no single individual can gain reputation to the answer involved. Because it is a wiki post all of good would be invited to muck with the response by adding information as one stumbles upon it.

I have done this recently on the Christianity SE site with some success. the question involved is as follows:

[How do Catholics observe Lent through a dignified and appropriate use of food?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/68163/25495)

This model shows how a question that is normally ***too broad*** can be placed into a single long running logical response without any single individual claiming reputation.

All of good will would be invited to muck with the response adding to one unique community wiki answer. And hopefully this could generate more interest in our [Beer, Wine & Spirits SE](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/tour) site.